# Calculating quintile based scores on R

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate-functions, quantile, tapply

I have a dataframe with year (2006 to 2010), 4 industry sectors, 150 firm names and the net income of these firms. In total I have 750 observations, one for each firm for each year. I want to give scores to firms for their income within each industry year based on the quintiles. So, firms with income in the top 20% within each industry-year get a score of 5, the next 20% get a score of 4 and so on. The bottom 20% get a score of 1.

The sample data base is:

```
Year Industry Firm Income
2006 Chemicals ABC 334.50
2007 Chemicals ABC 388.98
.
.
2006 Pharma XYZ 91.45
.
.
```

How do I do this in R? I have tried `aggregate` and `tapply` along with `quantile` but am not able to arrive at the logic that should be used for this. Please help.

I tried this just to allocate a score of 1 to the lowest 20%, but it returned an error.

```
db10$score <- ifelse(db10$income < aggregate(income~Year+industry,db10,quantile,c(0.2)),1,0)
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your dataset?

Comment: Posted a typical sample of the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

First, I'll create the sample where to test the function below:

```
y = c(rep(2001,15),rep(2002,15),rep(2003,15))
ind = c("A","B","C","D","E","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P")
val = runif(45,10,100)
df = data.frame(y,ind,val)

head(df,20)

      y ind      val
1  2001   A 63.32011
2  2001   B 85.67976
3  2001   C 86.77527
4  2001   D 32.18319
5  2001   E 49.86626
6  2001   G 57.73214
7  2001   H 18.08216
8  2001   I 22.31012
9  2001   J 44.11174
10 2001   K 54.76902
11 2001   L 41.82495
12 2001   M 64.84514
13 2001   N 59.16529
14 2001   O 61.28870
15 2001   P 84.76561
16 2002   A 83.68185
17 2002   B 45.01354
18 2002   C 62.22964
19 2002   D 98.41717
20 2002   E 19.91548
```

There are 3 years, and industries from A to P.  The data frame is ordered by year and later by industry.

This function below takes a year value `y` and calculates the quintile category for all `df$val` where the year `df$y` is `y`

```
quintile = function(y) {
    x = df$val[df$y == y]
    qn = quantile(x, probs = (0:5)/5)
    result = as.numeric(cut(x, qn, include.lowest = T))
}
```

The only thing left is to apply this function to the unique year values

```
df$qn = unlist(lapply(unique(df$y), quintile))
```

Result:

```
> head(df,20)
      y ind      val qn
1  2001   A 63.32011  4
2  2001   B 85.67976  5
3  2001   C 86.77527  5
4  2001   D 32.18319  1
5  2001   E 49.86626  2
6  2001   G 57.73214  3
7  2001   H 18.08216  1
8  2001   I 22.31012  1
9  2001   J 44.11174  2
10 2001   K 54.76902  3
11 2001   L 41.82495  2
12 2001   M 64.84514  4
13 2001   N 59.16529  3
14 2001   O 61.28870  4
15 2001   P 84.76561  5
16 2002   A 83.68185  4
17 2002   B 45.01354  1
18 2002   C 62.22964  3
19 2002   D 98.41717  5
20 2002   E 19.91548  1
```

Maybe there is a much simpler way to implement this...

**Grouping by two columns**

If you want to calculate quintiles based on the grouping of two columns: `y` and `grp`

```
y = c(rep(2001,15),rep(2002,15),rep(2003,15))
grp = c("G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G2","G2","G2","G2","G2","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3")
ind = c("A","B","C","D","E","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P")
val = round(runif(45,10,100))
df = data.frame(y,grp,ind,val)

> head(df,20)
      y grp ind val
1  2001  G1   A  40
2  2001  G1   B  33
3  2001  G1   C  65
4  2001  G1   D  99
5  2001  G1   E  18
6  2001  G2   G  36
7  2001  G2   H  15
8  2001  G2   I  17
9  2001  G2   J  42
10 2001  G2   K  67
11 2001  G3   L  60
12 2001  G3   M  34
13 2001  G3   N  61
14 2001  G3   O  76
15 2001  G3   P  15
16 2002  G1   A  18
17 2002  G1   B  15
18 2002  G1   C  44
19 2002  G1   D  79
20 2002  G1   E  22
```

Then use:

```
quintile = function(z) {
    x = df$val[df$y == z[1] & df$grp == z[2]]
    qn = quantile(x, probs = (0:5)/5)
    result = as.numeric(cut(x, qn, include.lowest = T))
}


df$qn = as.vector(apply(unique(df[,c("y","grp")]),1, quintile))
```

Result:

```
> head(df,20)
      y grp ind val qn
1  2001  G1   A  40  3
2  2001  G1   B  33  2
3  2001  G1   C  65  4
4  2001  G1   D  99  5
5  2001  G1   E  18  1
6  2001  G2   G  36  3
7  2001  G2   H  15  1
8  2001  G2   I  17  2
9  2001  G2   J  42  4
10 2001  G2   K  67  5
11 2001  G3   L  60  3
12 2001  G3   M  34  2
13 2001  G3   N  61  4
14 2001  G3   O  76  5
15 2001  G3   P  15  1
16 2002  G1   A  18  2
17 2002  G1   B  15  1
18 2002  G1   C  44  4
19 2002  G1   D  79  5
20 2002  G1   E  22  3
```

I this example, `y` would be the year and `grp` the industry group, `ind` the firms and `val` the income.

Pay attention to the order of `c("y","grp")` inside the `apply` and the columns names inside the quintile function. You'll have to replace them with the column names you want.

Be warned that if your groups are small (in this example 5 firms per group), the quintiles may not be unique and an error will pop-up.

**Using column names from question**

```
quintile = function(z) {
    x = df$Income[df$Year == z[1] & df$Industry == z[2]]
    qn = quantile(x, probs = (0:5)/5)
    result = as.numeric(cut(x, qn, include.lowest = T))
}


df$qn = as.vector(apply(unique(df[,c("Year","Industry")]),1, quintile))
```

Before applying this, the data frame `df` must be ordered by Year and Industry.

Comment: @RSchifini Thanks a lot, the code works for your values. But. I'm sorry, I think I did not make myself clear. I want quintile scores to be applied within each industry-year. For one year (say 2001), the industry A may have many firms (A1, A2, A3...). The scoring needs to work within these firms (A1, A2, A3...)  for every year.

Comment: @Rschifini I get an error saying `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "qn", value = list(`1` = c(3, 5, 5,  : 
  replacement has 30 rows, data has 2398` I have 5 year data and 6 groups and that is why the 30. I renamed my variables as per your code and ran it.

Comment: Is your data ordered by year first and then industry? I'll add the code for your column names